# Gap between header in custom page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

I've got a really interesting problem. I've just start today to creating a wordpress theme, everything is going good until I create a custom page. Anyway I was created this "home" page then linked to my custom made "frontpage" template via control panel. Then I realize that there is a gap between header and browser bar.

Here is the ss: http://i43.tinypic.com/2q2o13b.png the gap is approximately: 15px. Its only happen when I linked my pages to custom made page.(and custom page's codes are same with the default page)

However lets look like the normal page. Nothing is linked. Default template.

Here is the ss2: http://i43.tinypic.com/2w5u05e.png

No problem with that.

Actually I try to implement margin-top:-8px in body tag. Home page is fix with this but this time normal pages are broken :/

Guys I really need your help, otherwise I havent got any hair on my head. Sorry for my bad English btw. Hope you'll understand my problem.

PS:

css file: http://snipt.org/embed/ALje3
 default page file: http://snipt.org/ALjf1
 custom page file(frontpage): http://snipt.org/ALjg6 , right now same with the default page only i add it to first 4-5 lines

oh and I also try disabled the admin bar, checked my  tags, etc.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Put link to real page - it will be easer to find something using firebug (in forefox). Btw: most browsers have 8px margin for html and body so most pages use `html, body { margin: 0 }` as first rule - see [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com). Sometimes inner element margin goes outside outer element and you can get strange margin. Sometimes editors save files in utf-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and you can get strange margin too,

Comment: Some example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ52j/1) - `H1` margin goes outside `div`. Use `h1 { margin: 0; }` or `div { overflow: auto; }` in example to see difference.

Comment: Your ss1 and ss2 links are broken.

Comment: @furas I try your advice but it's not work. here is the live version of my theme, you can check it here: http://testdeneme123.net46.net/wordpress/

Comment: @darksoulsong right now I open with different browser&ip and it is opened..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your page to file and I opened that file in browser and I saw chars `ďťż` in top left corner.

[image]

This means that your editor save files in UTF-8 with BOM. BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) is few bytes at the beginning of file with information for editor. You can't see it in editor. Browser sometimes display that bytes as `ďťż` but sometimes it uses space chars in that place - and this gives you unexpected margin.

If your editor doesn't have `Save in UTF-8 without BOM` or `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM` (or something similar) you have to change editor - for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) (Windows) or [Geany](http://www.geany.org) (Windows, Linux)

Comment: thank you so much sir! You saved my hair. :) My IDE is Dreamweaver CC btw.